# MacBook Air can not "see" an old-ish (2011) camera which is connected to it via USB

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, camera, canon

I have a MacBook Air (M1, 2020) running Ventura 13.5.2, and am trying to connect my camera (Canon PowerShot SX220 HS, released 2011) to it via USB. The Mac only has USB-C ports, and the camera only has a USB-A cable, but I join them using an adapter. No matter what I do, the Mac does not "see" the camera, either in "Finder", or when I type `ls /Volumes` at a command prompt.

Sometimes "Disk Utility" can show an external drive which is not automatically connected, but that does not "see" the camera either.

I know the adapter is okay because I have tested it independently. I know the cable and camera are okay, because I can connect the camera to either a Windows laptop or my old Linux desktop.

Is there anything I do to make my Mac "see" this device which I know is connected to it?

---

**Extra information**: It appears under System Information -> USB devices

```
USB 3.1 Bus:

Host Controller Driver: AppleT8103USBXHCI

Canon Digital Camera:

Product ID: 0x322c
Vendor ID:  0x04a9  (Canon Inc.)
Version:    0.02
Serial Number:  [redacted]
Speed:  Up to 480 Mb/s
Manufacturer:   Canon Inc.
Location ID:    0x01100000 / 1
Current Available (mA): 500
Current Required (mA):  2
Extra Operating Current (mA):   0
```

Also, according to this [Canon page](https://asia.canon/en/support/6200102000) the file format is "Design rule for Camera File system, DPOF (Version1.1) compliant", whatever that is.

Comment: According to this Canon page https://asia.canon/en/support/6200102000 the file format is "Design rule for Camera File system, DPOF (Version1.1) compliant", whatever that is.

Comment: Download the images to my Mac.

Comment: That works too - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish I had a sure fire solution, but since the USB device codes are recognized, you now need drivers if neither Image Capture nor Photos sees content from the camera. The best I can think of is trying this for a free evaluation just in case one of their reverse engineered Canon scanner drivers works with the firmware on that camera.

- https://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/canon_8800f.html

Also, be sure to fire up [Image Capture](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/image-capture/imgcp1004/mac) which comes from Apple to see if it can [read any photos on the internal storage](https://community.usa.canon.com/t5/Camera-Software/PowerShot-SX260-HS-macOS-drivers-needed-to-connect-to-MacBook/m-p/450807#M18212) and be very patient if the camera doesn’t immediately go into the mode where storage is presented to the computer.

Comment: Ok I have progress... I can see the entire camera contents on Image Capture. Previously it did not, so I am not sure what has changed!

Comment: Hooray! It shouldn’t show up in Finder AFAIK - and weren’t those amazing cameras for the money? Great design, feature, size and optics paired with very nice electronics for the day.